# Extract noise vector after using imnoise

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a vector in which I have added a Gaussian white noise (with zero mean and standard deviation 0.001). More particularly, I used the `imnoise` function in MATLAB as:

```
pixel_noisy = imnoise(original_pixel, 'Gaussian', 0, 0.001);
```

**My question:** is there a way to extract the noise vector that has been added to the original pixel? The noise vector has been added automatically after the use of `imnoise`. Although that, is it possible to know what was this noise vector?

Any help will be very appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following  relation holds between the original and the noisy image:

```
pixel_noisy = original_pixel + noise
```

Therefore, the noise can be calculated using a subtraction:

```
noise = original_pixel - pixel_noisy
```

**Validation**

You can validate this method by checking if the noise is indeed a Gaussian distribution:

```
n = 100; % size of the image
original_pixel = rand(n, n); % constructs a random image
pixel_noisy = imnoise(original_pixel, 'Gaussian', 0, 0.001); % add noise
noise = pixel_noisy - original_pixel; % calculate the noise

mean = mean2(noise) % check the mean (should be 0)
variance = std2(noise)^2 % check the variance (should be 0.001)
```

For larger values of `n`, the `mean` and `variance` should match better their desired values.